# Using wrapfigure, why does lipsum text wrap OK, but ordinary text does not?

Tags: graphics, formatting

```
%
% ------ Would like to use the Exercise environment ------ %
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass[demo]{book}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{relsize} %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % unit of degree
\usepackage{caption} %


\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
    \usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop}
    \usepackage{layout}
    \usepackage{graphicx} %
    \usepackage[lastexercise, answerdelayed]{exercise}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{lipsum}  % generates filler text
    \usepackage{setspace} %
    %
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} % 1mm=2.834646pt; 1pt=0.3515mm
    %
    \graphicspath{ {book_questions/images/} }
    %
    \begin{document}
    %
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
    \setstretch{1.25}

\Question{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\parbox{0.6\textwidth}{Show that the distance \hspace{0.4pt}$x$ \hspace{0.6pt}from the centre of the crank to the piston pin\hspace{0.6pt}, expressed in terms of the connecting rod length \hspace{0.8pt}$p$\hspace{0.4pt}, \hspace{0.8pt}the crank radius \hspace{0.4pt}$r$\hspace{0.3pt}, \hspace{0.8pt}and the crank angle \hspace{2.4pt}$\theta$\hspace{0.4pt}, \hspace{1.2pt}satisfies\hspace{0.6pt}, \hspace{0.6pt}implicitly, \hspace{0.6pt}the following equation\hspace{0.6pt}:}
&
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
%        \caption{Lithium-ion battery operation}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../my_book/book_questions/fig_01_piston_accel}
        \label{fig:LIB_image}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
 }

    \begingroup % using required text 
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} %
    \setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} %
    \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{46mm}
      \centering
        \includegraphics[width=42mm]{fig_01_piston_accel}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
    \noindent Show that the distance \hspace{0.4pt}$x$ \hspace{0.6pt}from the centre of the crank to the piston pin\hspace{0.6pt}, expressed in terms of the connecting rod length \hspace{0.8pt}$p$\hspace{0.4pt}, \hspace{0.8pt}the crank radius \hspace{0.4pt}$r$\hspace{0.3pt}, \hspace{0.8pt}and the crank angle \hspace{2.4pt}$\theta$\hspace{0.4pt}, \hspace{1.2pt}satisfies\hspace{0.6pt}, \hspace{0.6pt}implicitly, \hspace{0.6pt}the following equation\hspace{0.6pt}:
    \endgroup

    \vspace{120pt}

    \begingroup % using lipsum text
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} %
    \setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} %
    \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{45mm}
      \centering
        \includegraphics[width=40mm]{fig_01_piston_accel}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]

    \endgroup

    \clearpage

    % --------------------- Inside of Execise enviroment ------------------------ %

    \begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_exer_01}]

    \Question{
    \begingroup % using required text ******
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} %
    \setlength{\columnsep}{10pt} %
    \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{45mm}
      \centering
        \includegraphics[width=40mm]{fig_01_piston_accel}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
    \noindent Show that the distance \hspace{0.4pt}$x$ \hspace{0.6pt}from the centre of the crank to the piston pin\hspace{0.6pt}, expressed in terms of the connecting rod length \hspace{0.8pt}$p$\hspace{0.4pt}, \hspace{0.8pt}the crank radius \hspace{0.4pt}$r$\hspace{0.3pt}, \hspace{0.8pt}and the crank angle \hspace{2.4pt}$\theta$\hspace{0.4pt}, \hspace{1.2pt}satisfies\hspace{0.6pt}, \hspace{0.6pt}implicitly, \hspace{0.6pt}the following equation\hspace{0.6pt}:
    \endgroup }

    \vspace{120pt}
    \Question{
    \begingroup % using lipsum text ******
    \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} %
    \setlength{\columnsep}{11pt} %
    \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{45mm}
      \centering
        \includegraphics[width=40mm]{fig_01_piston_accel}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]

    \endgroup }

    \end{Exercise}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: you are ending the paragraph outside the group, that is never going to work with wrapfig

Comment: @David Carlisle  Sorry, I omitted to include \Question{  } in the way I have now edited the original.  Your "space-before \endgroup" works, but not when the \Question{  } is introduced.  What is the alternative to \begingroup, \endgroup which I thought was a logical method of containing commands locally?

Comment: works for me, if I put a blank line in front of the extra `\endgroup` you added although Question is a list and in general you can not use wrapfig in combination with lists.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  When setting questions, a figure is often a necessity.  Can you suggest an alternative, please, to achieve what I am attempting here?

Comment: @David Carlisle  Reviewing your paragraph above: "works for me", are you saying it worked for you when the whole is enclosed inside a \Question?

Comment: I think thats what I meant, let me check: taking the code as currently in the question and adding some blank lines....

Comment: Someone downvoted the question, but I upvoted back to 0. Seems like a decent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need a blank line before the `\endgroup` so that the paragraph ends without losing the wrapfig settings. (but `\begingroup` `\endgroup` are not really latex syntax intended for document use)

Comment: I spotted a "tabular" solution on the right of the this page which I have incorporated into my original code.  It appears to work perfectly except that I would like the question number to be at the top of the result - rather than midway down.  Can that be adjusted?

Comment: Would you be kind enough to review recent comments on this question, and hopefully, we can reach a conclusion.

Comment: @keith77777 probably unrelated to the original question but you have used vertcaly centred  parbiox and minipage perhaps you are looking for `\parbox[t]{..}{..}` and `\begin{minipage}[t]{..}...`

Comment: Sorry, \parbox[t]{} and \begin{minpage}[t], etc. does not move the question number from being vertically centered.  Should I ask a fresh question?

Comment: I am accepting the answer to the question as posed namely,  that \wrapfig cannot be used within an Exercise/Question environment.